# JavaScript isn't read correctly in HTMLQuestion

Tags: javascript, html, mechanicalturk

I made a simple application using the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472354/fix-a-zoom-in-and-out-coding) and ran it to test it on the worker sandbox MTurk site. It works perfectly when using the code shown in the answer, but if I try to create an object and place the function and variables in the object, the buttons won't work on the sandbox site but will work when opening the .html file in a browser. Additionally, adding comments will produce the same effect. The code I have is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<HTMLQuestion xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2011-11-11/HTMLQuestion.xsd">
  <HTMLContent><![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #thediv {
     align-self:flex-start
     margin:0 auto;
     height:1050px;
     width:750px;
     overflow:auto;
    }
    img {
     position: static;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='button' value ='-' onclick='zoom(0.5);'/>
    <input type='button' value ='+' onclick='zoom(2);'/>
    <div id="thediv">
        <img id="pic" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Nokota_Horses_cropped.jpg"/>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var zoomLevel=1;
    var maxZoomLevel=2;
    var minZoomLevel=1;
    function zoom(zm) {
        var img=document.getElementById("pic");
        if(zm > 1){
            if(zoomLevel < maxZoomLevel){
                zoomLevel++;
            }else{
                return;
            }
        }else if(zm < 1){
            if(zoomLevel > minZoomLevel){
                zoomLevel--;
            }else{
                return;
            }
        }
        wid = img.width;
        ht = img.height;
        img.style.width = (wid*zm)+"px";
        img.style.height = (ht*zm)+"px";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
]]>
  </HTMLContent>
  <FrameHeight>450</FrameHeight>
</HTMLQuestion>
```

Is there a reason certain things will work in browser but not in the MTurk sandbox site?

Comment: Are there any console errors ?

Comment: @mplungjan Not in the MATLAB SDK I use to send it to MTurk and none in browser.

Comment: Are you using an HTMLQuestion or ExternalQuestion? If ExternalQuestion, where are you hosting the HTML?

Comment: @jrb HTMLQuestion, using a .question xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested creating a HIT like this and it worked for me.

Unrelated to the JavaScript, note that you will need to include at least one named input (eg ) in order for Workers to submit the HIT.

What browser are you testing in?

Comment: I've been using Google Chrome to access the website but I've tested the .html file in Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Chrome.